# Segmentation Fault in rvm'd Ruby on Mac when running RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, segmentation-fault, rubygems, rvm

I was developing something at the uni, saved to my Dropbox intending to continue at home. This is the message that greeted me:

```
$ spec graph_spec.rb 
/Users/amadan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc1/gems/PriorityQueue-0.1.2/ext/priority_queue/CPriorityQueue.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
```

However,

```
$ `which spec` graph_spec.rb 
...........................................................................

Finished in 0.046973 seconds

75 examples, 0 failures
```

What the heck is going on here?

For the reference:

```
$ which spec
/Users/amadan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc1/bin/spec
```

UPDATE: I just noticed the 1.8.7 there... how did it get there? The top of the spec file says:

```
$ head `which spec`
#!/Users/amadan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc1/bin/ruby
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'rspec' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'
```

Where does it say "run 1.8.7"?!?

Comment: You'd need to show your $PATH to get an answer.

Comment: `which` gives the file that is first in `$PATH`. After that, ruby should be loaded by the absolute path in the hash-bang line. Thus, in the only place I can envision `$PATH` to be relevant, I give enough information by the output of the `which spec` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that RVM is messing your gems and rubies. I would recommend testing on a cleaned up RVM installation (with only 1.9 installed).

Is `/Users/amadan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc1/bin/ruby`really ruby 1.9.2 ?

Other way to test would be to explicitely run `ruby spec` so you are sure this is really 1.9.2 which is called.

To conclude, Segfaults do happen in ruby (esp. on 1.8) and are sometimes avoided by reorganizing slightly the ruby code. Good Luck !

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll mark this as correct, as I too think there's something funky that went on with RVM, but in fact the question has become irrelevant in the year since... I'm still equally puzzled by what happened, I just don't need to solve it any more.